# Windows explorer or alternatives won't show fonts folder with over 24 000 files

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, fonts

I downloaded a bunch of fonts a while ago. Without too much considering it, I installed 24 000 of them - which, obviously, resulted in many of my programs becoming very slow. I was about to remove the extra fonts, but apparently `explorer.exe` and alternatives refuse to display the contents of the folder due to too many files.

I was thinking of a program to go through the files and remove ones that have been modified at time X, but apparently the modification time of the font files stay at when they were created/modified, not when they were installed, so I need a little help here.

Has anyone dealt with a problem like this before, and also found a solution? Thanks in advance.
Also, I don't have very many system restore points, so that's not really an option here.

Comment: I'd imagine a Power Shell script or cleverly written DOS command may be able to blindly move the files into others folders in groups of X, but sadly my Script-DOS Fu is not strong enough to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)? It will allow you to view all the files and manipulate them based on Creation Date.

Comment: Thank you. I actually had a restore point after all, but this will be useful in the future if I (or someone else) happen to have a similar problem.

Comment: Restore points in Windows 7 are very nice. Glad you came right.